# Methods which doesn't return anything can be run on a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to optimize a code.

There is a  function which do few things internally and doesn't return anything. i.e void function.

and there is no impact of that function on subsequent codes after it .

Is it good to run these kinds of methods in separate thread , as it could increase performance.

Comment: Does the method access shared state (e.g. instance variables), what parameter does it have?

Comment: Depends what it does and what you're doing with it.

Comment: thread-safety is not defined by what a method returns but by what it does

Answer (score 1):

Yes it may increase performance. It will save the time that method takes to run.But need to check [thread safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) .

So if there is no issue with thread safety multi threading will increase performance.